# How to create a variable inside of a play twirl template?

Tags: scala, playframework, twirl

I have a model that I pass to my view that looks like:

```
IndexModel(productSales: Seq[ProductSale])

case class ProductSale(id: Int, name: String, soldAt: java.time.ZonedDateTime)
```

Now I want to display a list of the product sales, but I put a header for the **Day** and then list all the sales for that day so like:

**July 10th, 2016**

product 1

product 2

**July 11th, 2016**

product 24
product 2234

The only way I can think of doing this would require me to store the current day in a variable, so pseudo code would be:

```
@currentDay = -1
@for(ps <- model.ProductSales) {

  @if(currentDay != ps.SoldAt.getDayOfMonth) {
     <h1>@ps.soldAt</h1>
     @currentDay = ps.SoldAt.getDayOfMonth
  }

  <li>@ps.name - @ps.id </li>

}
```

How should I go about doing this using twirl?

Answer (score 0):

Try (didn't test):

```
@for(currentDate <- model.productSales.map(_.soldAt).distinct) {
  <h1>@currentDate</h1>  
  @for(ps <- model.productSales.filter(_.soldAt == currentDate) {
    <li>@ps.name - @ps.id</li>
  }
}
```

If you want to declare a variable you need to use `@defining(){...}` - read more here: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaTemplates#Declaring-reusable-values